# Agregar registros a un array asociativo con un botón

Tags: php, array, post, pilas

los saludo y les pido ayuda ya que no se en que me estoy equivocando y ojala alguien pueda ayudar, deseo realizar una lista de N campos en un array asociativo por medio de un boton "Agregar" el array tiene la estructura campo1->valor1, campo2->valor2, campo3->valor3 .... y deseo insertar cada valor de los campos con un boton submit, todo funciona bien, los valores de los campos se conservan al actualizar la pagina pero no el arreglo, el arreglo solo inserta un registro y se "resetea" cada que se presiona el boton "agreagar" de tal forma que solo los ultimos valores se insertan en el registro 0, podrian apoyarme en saber donde tengo el error, les dejo el codigo para 3 campos y muchas gracias por sus siempre acertadas respuestas :

```
<?php ob_start(); ?> 
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<head>
    <title>arreglos 2</title>
</head>
<body>

        <?php   
            
            echo "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='arreglo' value='$arreglo'>";           
            $camp1=$_POST['camp1'];
            $camp2=$_POST['camp2'];
            $camp3=$_POST['camp3'];
        
            if (@$_POST['botmov']=='agregar')
            {               
                $arreglo['campo1']=$camp1;
                $arreglo['campo2']=$camp2;
                $arreglo['campo3']=$camp3;
                
                //array_push($arreglo['campo1'],$camp1)
                //array_push($arreglo['campo2'],$camp2)
                //array_push($arreglo['campo3'],$camp3)
            
            }
            
            echo "<tr><td><b>campo1:</b> <input type='text' name='camp1' value='{$camp1}' class='form-control'></td>";          
            echo "<tr><td><b>campo2:</b> <input type='text' name='camp2' value='{$camp2}' class='form-control'></td>";          
            echo "<tr><td><b>campo3:</b> <input type='text' name='camp3' value='{$camp3}' class='form-control'></td>";          
        
            echo " <input type=submit name='botmov' value='agregar'>";          
            
            echo '<table>';         
                
            foreach ($arreglo as $campo=>$valor) 
            {
              echo "<td>$campo ";
              echo "<td>$valor<tr>";
            }
                
            echo "</table>";            
            print_r($arreglo);  
        ?>  
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: imagina que tienes una archivero de 3 niveles; y metes los datos en el primer nivel... luego pasas al rato y abres el archivero y los datos no esta... que crees que haya pasado?

Comment: No estás definiendo `$arreglo`, defínelo fuera del `if`de este modo: `$arreglo=array();` luego, dentro del `if`, debes irlo llenando así: `$arreglo[]=array('campo1'=>$campo1, 'campo2'=>$camp2, 'campo3'=>$camp3);` La clave es esto `[]` antes del signo de `=`.

Comment: Estimado  ArcanisGK507
Gracias por tu respuesta pero analizando tu pregunta yo creo que a los datos están en otro nivel pero no entiendo bie n la pregunta o me faltan datos, seguire pensandolo.

Comment: Estimado A. Cedano, gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo de la forma que me dices funciona casi igual que el código original, es decir, solo inserta un registro y no lo acumula como una pila, de hecho se comporta como un array dentro de otro array, tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal, les dejo el codigo corregido con tus observaciones

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?> 
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<head>
    <title>arreglos 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
    echo "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'";
    $arreglo=array();
    $camp1=$_POST['camp1'];
    $camp2=$_POST['camp2'];
    $camp3=$_POST['camp3'];
            
    if (@$_POST['botmov']=='agregar')
    {   
        $arreglo[]=array('campo1'=>$camp1, 'campo2'=>$camp2, 'campo3'=>$camp3);
    }           
    echo "<tr><td><b>campo1:</b> <input type='text' name='camp1' value='{$camp1}'></td>";           
    echo "<tr><td><b>campo2:</b> <input type='text' name='camp2' value='{$camp2}'></td>";           
    echo "<tr><td><b>campo3:</b> <input type='text' name='camp3' value='{$camp3}'></td>";       
    echo " <input type=submit name='botmov' value='agregar'>";          
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($arreglo as $campo=>$valor) 
    {
        echo "<td>$campo ";
        echo "<td>$valor<tr>";
    }       
    echo "</table>";            
    print_r($arreglo);
?>  
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).